# Flex profiler gives "Socket timeout " error. Why for?

Tags: apache-flex, profiler

When trying to run the Flex Builder 3 profiler on any I don't get the profiler dialog window and then after a few seconds I get "Socket timeout" in the console window.  Any ideas why it can't connect?

I've got the latest debug version of Flash player and have tried shutting off my firewall.
I'm running it on XP from the local drive, ie. not through localhost.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the browser (Firefox in my case) has to be shutdown before the profiler is started.  Step 1. in the livedocs even says this -- wish I had read it earlier.  :)

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=profiler_3.html

Answer (score 0):

Browser tabs, make sure you have latest debug as you said you did, also make sure that the port is correct, for some reason the port sometimes changes(1001 or 20957) from the default 9999, be sure that your mm.cfg has ProfilingFileOutputEnable=1 and that bittorrent isn't on.
hth

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your firewall does not block port 9999, you can customize the port number too: Open Preferences->Flex->Profiler->Connections.

Answer (score 0):

While I try to run my Flex Profiler I got this error message:
In the flash application I got the following exception:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation:
    file:///C|%2Fwork%2Flabsense%2Fbranches%2Frel%5F1%5F2%5F5%5FEA%2Fsources%2Fui%2F.metadata%2F.plugins%2Fcom.adobe.flash.profiler%2FProfilerAgent.swf?host=localhost&port=9999
    cannot load data from localhost:9999.
    at ProfilerAgent()[C:\SVN\branches\3.2.0\modules\profiler3\as\ProfilerAgent.as:127]
```

And in the flex Profiler console (at the eclipse) I got : Socket timeout.

I am run on windows vista,
Flex builder: 3.2
Flash debugger: 10,0,22,87

Things that I have done to resolve this issue:

- Switch the connection port of the profiler to 9998 (and back)
- Remove and reinstall the flash debugger player.
- Install flex builder 3.2 (instead of 3.0)
- Delete all the enters in the mm.cfg file
- Add enter to the mm.cfg:

  ```
  PreloadSwf=C:\work\labsense\Sources\ui\.metadata\.plugins\com.adobe.flash.profiler\ProfilerAgent.swf?host=localhost&port=9999
  ```

  or

  ```
  PreloadSwf=C:\work\labsense\Sources\ui\.metadata\.plugins\com.adobe.flash.profiler\ProfilerAgent.swf?host=localhost&port=9998
  ```

  or

  ```
  PreloadSwf=C:/work/labsense/Sources/ui/.metadata/.plugins/com.adobe.flash.profiler/ProfilerAgent.swf?host=localhost&port=9999
  ```

  or with spaces:

  ```
  PreloadSwf=C: \ work \ labsense \ Sources \ ui \ .metadata \ .plugins \ com.adobe.flash.profiler \ ProfilerAgent.swf?host=localhost&port=9999
  ```

  or

  ```
  C:\work\labsense\Sources\ui\.metadata\.plugins\com.adobe.flash.profiler\ProfilerAgent.swf?
  ```

  or add all or some of the enters:

  ```
  TraceOutputFileName=C:\Users\zivo\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs\flashlog.txt
  ErrorReportingEnable=1
  MaxWarnings=0
  TraceOutputFileEnable=1
  ProfilingFileOutputEnable=1
  ```
- Turn on and off the vista firewall
- Add exception for port 9999 in the vista firewall
- Try to run the profiler SWF separately

Same result.
Try one last thing:
Because I have expreins problem little bit similar before with the flash debugger, the resolution then was:

1. Right click on flash player (debugger),
2. choose “Debugger”,
3. choose “other machine”
4. add “127.0.0.1”
5. click ok

then, it solve the issue (but apparently he connect to the debugger with host 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost (which is a same)
I now add to the **mm.cfg** file, the follow entry:

```
PreloadSwf=C:/work/labsense/branches/rel_1_2_5_EA/sources/ui/.metadata/.plugins/com.adobe.flash.profiler/ProfilerAgent.swf?host=127.0.0.1&port=9999
```

Then, after saving, I run the profiler, and its work!!

And the reasons for all this was:
Some program change the file **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts** to:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2006 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       iDBO # LMS GENERATED LINE
```

This means that localhost is not lead to 127.0.0.1!!!
Fixing is easy:

```
# ::1             localhost
# 127.0.0.1       iDBO # LMS GENERATED LINE
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Instead (remark the problem and fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Check /etc/hosts (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts), and see if it contains a line:
127.0.0.1 localhost
In my case, it was somehow changed to ::1 localhost, and that's why it stopped working.

Thanks to Ziv for the (poorly formatted) answer.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the other suggestions here, this post on Adobe's forum clued me in.
[Adobe forum](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/248762)

When the Flash debug player launches, it looks for mm.cfg in %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%. On this particular computer that path is not my home directory on C: but on the file server mapped to I:. So once I created I:\mm.cfg with the contents

```
PreloadSwf=C:\Users\ehedstrom\Documents\FLEXBU~1\.metadata\.plugins\com.adobe.flash.profiler\ProfilerAgent.swf?host=localhost&port=9999
```

everything magically started working!